# InfoPath Form auto populate drop down from drop down

Tags: infopath, dropdown, infopath-rules

How do you set InfoPath drop down choice fields to auto fill based on user selection from a primary field that is connected to a list with training courses with fields for course titles, type, source, material, etc. How can I set other fields to auto fill based on the selected course title drop down field?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of InfoPath you're using, but I was able to create cascading dropdowns on an InfoPath 2007 form using Rules.  When the first field isn't blank, populate the second dropdown using a data connection that filtered its values based on the value of the first dropdown.

Comment: I'm using InfoPath 2010. Each of the fields are a Drop-Down List Box. I have tried to create the rule to set each of the fields values when the Title field is changed. Here is the xpath that is generated. xdXDocument:GetDOM("Technical Skills and Knowledge")/dfs:myFields/dfs:queryFields/q:SharePointListItem_RW/q:ID[. = xdXDocument:get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:Training_Course/my:Source]

Comment: what is the xpath of the rule that you created to do this?